# Evolution of kafka-streams topology in production

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a complex topology including KStreams, KTables, joins, rekeying, filters, through, branching, zips etc with live clients on output topics.

All the input, intermidate and output topics are avro based topics.

How do I handle changes to the topology (adding new steps, new input-intermidate-output topics), knowing kafka-streams maintains internal state and changelogs, complying with the following business requirements:

- no data loss
- no data duplication (to a degree)
- no downtime

Is the answer lying somewhere between using `kafka-streams-application-reset` or creating brand new consumer group (application id)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, there is no checkpointing or savepoint type concept in Kafka Streams.

If you need to update the existing applications, it is safe to use the new application.id or reset the existing `application.id`.

There are scenarios where you need to define a new `application.id` based on the changes in topology.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Data+%28Re%29Processing+Scenarios

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What will happen to KStream-KTable join if I reset the appalication id? Is kafka-streams smart enough to repopulate KTable before joining with KStream?

Comment: Yes, normally the internal store on the Ktable will be charged from the underlying topic before the app is considering running and doing the transformations like joins.

Comment: If you reset the application Id, it deletes all the underlying changelog topics. Hence the ktable can't be repopulated. It will be new ktable created in the next run with new changelog topics and state store..

Comment: It depends on the timestamps. If the KTable records have smaller timestamps than the KStream records, the KTable records will be put into the KTable first (you will need version 2.1 -- in older versions, the timestamp synchronization is best effort only)

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your answers. Is there a way to not to duplicate whole stream on output topic in case of application id reset?

Comment: It will be safe to create the another topic or otherwise use the same key and perform compaction to remove the old records